# Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException Route [login] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I do not know what I am doing wrong please help. I am trying to update user password. Whenever I click submit button, the thing is going to bring error `"Route[login] not found"`. I have tried a lot on it I can't figure anything out please help.

```
public function userUpdatePassword(Request $request)
{
    //route view
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $data=$request->all();

        $this->validate($request,[
                'new_password' => 'required|min:10',                    
                'password_confirmation' => 'required|same:new_password'    
            ]);

        $user_id=Auth::user()->id;
        $old_password=User::where('id', $user_id)->first();
        $current_password=$data['current_password'];

        if (Hash::check($current_password, $old_password->password)) {
            //update password
            $new_password=bcrypt($data['new_password']);
            User::where('id', $user_id)->update(['password'=>$new_password]);

            return redirect()->back()->with("flash_message_success","The New Password Has been Updated");
        } else{
            return redirect()->back()->with("flash_message_error","The Current password  is Incorrect");
        }

        // echo '<pre>'; print_r($data);  die;
    }

    //return view('user.user_changepassword');
}
```

Comment: you don't have a route named 'login' defined ...

Comment: i am not using any route login

Comment: right, which is the issue, because something is trying to generate a URL to a route named 'login', like the `Authenticate` middleware, or potentially some view ... you will have to start looking through the stack traces of the errors you get

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your request is not including the authentication token required to perform the operation.
In my case I had this error and got it working as soon as I included the authentication info.

Check if you are sending the authentication token in your request

Comment: I am also facing the same problem once token expired it through the error instead error it should return the error in JSON format for API